# How to calculate d in RSA for my number with this

Tags: encryption, rsa

I took the p&q value as 61 & 53 and n=3233
e=17
d=?
How to find it?
Plz help me...

Comment: [This](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20932/555) and the description of the [Extended Euclidian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) might also help. Surprisingly, I fail to find a complete step by step answer performing $d=e^{-1}\bmod\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$ on our site!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't hard to find d!

We know $ed=1\bmod \phi(n)$.

$\phi(n)=\phi(61)\phi(53)=(60)(52)=3120$

So $17d=1\bmod 3120$. From the euclidean algorithm you can easily  find "d".

Comment: A more rigorous notations is writing $ed\equiv1\pmod{\phi(n)}$ or $ed\bmod\phi(n)=1$. Problem with $ed=1\bmod\phi(n)$ is that it can (and arguably should) be read $ed=(1\bmod\phi(n))$, that is $ed=1$. Also, $ed\equiv1\pmod{\phi(n)}$ is a sufficient condition, but is not necessary; the necessary and sufficient condition, used in [PKCS#1](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=7), is $ed\equiv1\pmod{\lambda(n)}$. $d=413$ is a valid private exponent, but $17\times413\bmod3120\ne1$.

Comment: Can u explain briefly??